# After updating to sdk version 23 my app crashes with some floating action button error?

Tags: java, android, gradle, floating-action-button

I have updated compile sdk version to 23 ,which brings me to list of error related to floating action button. couldnt able to fix it , any help highyl appreciated.

> 2019-11-06 15:11:26.767 2777-2777/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: xyz, PID: 2777
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xz.MediaPresentationActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #86: Binary XML file line #86: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3125)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3268)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1959)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7100)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #86: Binary XML file line #86: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #86: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:686)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:829)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:902)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:554)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:461)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:383)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:469)
>           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2858)
>           at com.syz.MediaPresentationActivity.onCreate(MediaPresentationActivity.java:1089)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3105)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3268)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1959)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7100)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.

---

> build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

   compileSdkVersion 23
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode timeCounter
        versionName "${version}"
    }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

}
```

-manifest..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xyz.e">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

<!-- Declares necessary features for the app to work -->


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <!--
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
           -->
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MediaPresentationActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="eFrame"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            >

        </activity>

       <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".SettingsActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY android:value="com.serv24.eframe.SettingsActivity" />
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <receiver android:name=".IncomingReceiver" android:label="Call Receiver"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Does the `shadow_mid_color` color exist in your project?

Comment: sorry i have updated my question , shadow was not  an issue , but my app crashes with above error on updaing to version 23 ,

Comment: *You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme*. Which app theme are you using?

Comment: can you please look at my manifest , i have used DeviceDefault theme

Comment: In your MediaPresentationActivity you are using @style/AppTheme

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using AndroidX instead of the old support library since it ensures better compatibility throughout libraries and api levels.

To start with that, add the following to your build.gradle

```
 implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Also use the assistant:
Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX

There might come up some errors at first but they should be fixed by replacing com.android etc with androidx instead and here are many posts to that topic.

Also you could try to directly address the Button using this inside the xml:

```
android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

Hope this helps :) Good luck!